# Name order in "elsarticle-num-names" bib style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, elsarticle

With the following document class:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
```

and the following bib file and style:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
```

`\bibliography{References}` or `\bibliography{IEEEfull,References}`

and using the `natbib` package, I had some problems with my references; for example, some of them were shown as “?” in the body of the text.

The problem got fixed by changing the style to the following:

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num-names}
```

Everything is perfect except for the order of the authors’ names. Thus, I have the following order:

```
First Name, Family Name, Title Vol (Number), (Year) Pages.
```

but I need to have Family names coming first so that I can have all the names alphabetically ordered. I am wondering if there are any changes that I can make to have this implemented based on the same document class (i.e., report) and bibliography style (i.e.,  elsarticle-num-names).

I also tried other bibliography styles but no perfect fix. For example, based on:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

Everything is fine but the URLs are not shown in the reference list. For example, everything related to the following item is shown except for the URL:

```
@ELECTRONIC{example,
  author = {{Tex}},

  month = {August},

  year = {2013},

  title = {{Description of a Reference Problem}},

  note = {Accessed August 2011},

  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com},
}
```

Many thanks in advance,

amiruw

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.